# Smartface Splashpage image Android

Tags: smartface.io

I am trying to attach image on Splashpage it works for IOS but it crash on Android on startapp.
Some additional setting or not allowed for android?

Answer (score 0):

On my experience, you need to set the Background image property in the visual designer otherwise the app will crash on Android (this is a strange bug in Smartface).

You can change the image in code later, but in the designer, the Background image property needs to be filled (not empty).

Hope this helps!